# MDB Bootstrap not working out properly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm using default layout and another template which extends it. I'm trying out mdb bootstrap free version but it is not working out properly. I'm thinking that something is wrong with linking in head-layouts file. I've also tried installing locally and that didn't work too.Maybe I'm missing out something basic here.

Layout :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>dataMS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Template extending layout -

```
<div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
<!--Indicators-->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!--/.Indicators-->
<!--Slides-->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="view hm-black-light">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="mask"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
            <p>First text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <!--Mask color-->
        <div class="view hm-black-strong">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="mask"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
            <p>Secondary text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <!--Mask color-->
        <div class="view hm-black-slight">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="mask"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
            <p>Third text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/.Slides-->
<!--Controls-->
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
<!--/.Controls-->
```

Comment: It is giving this https://imgur.com/a/hCWVf instead of https://mdbootstrap.com/content/bootstrap-images/#cards

Comment: Maybe it's because you are using Bootstrap 3 and MDB 4.4.1? Try using BS4 instead

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Tried out with bootstrap but beta didn't work! Infact it's giving more discrepancies

Answer (score 1):

You are using Bootstrap 3 while MDB is based on Bootstrap 4. B4 is not backwards compatible with Bootstrap 3, therefore, it won't work.  Download fresh package from here: 
https://mdbootstrap.com/getting-started/

place your code and it will work. I've just tested it.